# Message store unavailable! WAS 6.1

Tags: websphere, messaging, bus

I' m stuck on an issue and need your advice.

> Messaging Engine not coming UP (Error,
>   "com.ibm.ws.sib.msgstore.TransactionException: CWSIS1099E: An
>   unexpected exception has occurred. Exception:
>   com.ibm.ws.sib.msgstore.MessageStoreUnavailableException: Operation
>   not possible as MessageStore is unavailable! ")

Environment:- Sun OS 5.10, WAS 6.1, Messaging Engine is using File Store.

Here are the exceptions from the JVM logs:

```
[2/5/13 4:48:06:242 EST] 0000002a SibMessage    I   [bsl_msg_bus:jabds3203v61x2bsl.bsl_scorecard-bsl_msg_bus] CWSIS1567E: Messaging engine jabds3203v61x2bsl.bsl_scorecard-bsl_msg_bus cannot obtain the lock on its file store, which ensures it has exclusive access to the data.
[2/5/13 4:48:06:262 EST] 0000002a ServiceLogger I com.ibm.ws.ffdc.IncidentStreamImpl initialize FFDC0009I: FFDC opened incident stream file /usr/local/web/bsl/WAS/61x2/jabds3203v61x2bsl/logs/ffdc/bsl_scorecard_0000002a_13.02.05_04.48.06_0.txt
[2/5/13 4:48:06:273 EST] 0000002a ServiceLogger I com.ibm.ws.ffdc.IncidentStreamImpl resetIncidentStream FFDC0010I: FFDC closed incident stream file /usr/local/web/bsl/WAS/61x2/jabds3203v61x2bsl/logs/ffdc/bsl_scorecard_0000002a_13.02.05_04.48.06_0.txt
[2/5/13 4:48:06:282 EST] 0000002a ServiceLogger I com.ibm.ws.ffdc.IncidentStreamImpl open FFDC0009I: FFDC opened incident stream file /usr/local/web/bsl/WAS/61x2/jabds3203v61x2bsl/logs/ffdc/bsl_scorecard_0000002a_13.02.05_04.48.06_1.txt
[2/5/13 4:48:06:292 EST] 0000002a ServiceLogger I com.ibm.ws.ffdc.IncidentStreamImpl resetIncidentStream
```

I have tried flushing out the temp, and I'm thinking of flushing the file store once. Can anyone you advise if this is feasible, what the correct way to do it is, and where can I find it

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is, somehow, you are starting the server with a user that does not has read/write access rights to *file store* files, or can't change current directory to the folder containing these files again because of access rights (for example files belong to root and you start server with some other user). You'd see some kind of 'access denied' messages, possibly wrapped to an IOException in the FFDC files if this is the case .

This usually happens when someone accidentally starts server with root user, which is normally run by another user. This may cause change of ownership in newly generated files. When you switch back to normal user, you can't access these properly. So you may try a `chown -R` to the proper user at the file store folder to make sure you have proper rights.

Comment: Thanks Kurtcebe for the reply. I found resolution to issue, file store used by message engine in this case was being in use by some other app in same profile. Which was preventing the message engine to gain the lock on the file store. So simply, bouncing the other app helped us to resolve the issue.